# how to validate a nz-range-picker in a reactive-form on angular

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

I am using an nz-range-picker from the ng-Zorro library in an angular reactive form. I'm trying to do the typical validation of "Validators.required" like this:

```
private saleDateFormInitialization(): void  {
    this.saleDateForm = this.fb.group({
      id: [ ,[], ],
      name: [ ,[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)], ],
      inscriptionDates: [, [,Validators.required], ],
      comment: [ ,[Validators.maxLength(255)], ],
      deliveryDate: [ ,[Validators.required,this.validateWeekendDays], ],
    },{ validators: [this.validateDeliveryDate]});
  }
```

and in the html file I have the following validation:

```
<shp-error-message *ngIf="saleDateForm.controls['inscriptionDates'].touched && saleDateForm.controls['inscriptionDates'].hasError('required')"
         [message]="getInscriptionDatesErrorMessage()">
       </shp-error-message>
```

My problem occurs when entering the start date, the error message automatically skips before giving me the chance to complete the end date. This occurs even though I didn't click outside the input...

I tried manipulating the different properties that the form-controls have but I didn't succeed.
I want the error message to be shown only if the user clicks outside the input .